# Angular 4 - Catching the err object from Service To Component

Tags: javascript, spring, angular, error-handling

I'm working on a login page with angular as front-end and spring-security as back-end, everything seems to be working fine, but when i try to handle the exception by catching the error from the service to the component is not working.

**service.ts**

```
 login(form) {
      var objectToSend = 'j_username=' + form.j_username + '&j_password=' + form.j_password;
      const headers = new Headers(
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
      );
      const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers, withCredentials: true});
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/***********/authenticate', objectToSend, options)
        .map((res) => res)
        .catch((error: any) => {
          if (error.status === 401) {
            console.log(error.status + ' is the current status');
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          } else if (error.status === 400) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          } else if (error.status === 409) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          } else if (error.status === 406) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
          }
        });
    }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
     loginProcess() {
      this._authenticationService.login(this.form.value).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.data = res;
          if (res.status === 200) {
            this._authenticationService.getRoles().subscribe(
              resp => {
                if (resp.status === 200) {
                  this.roles = JSON.parse(resp.text());
                  this.role = this.roles[0].authority;
                  localStorage.setItem('role', this.role);
                  this.connectedUser.eusLogin = this.form.value.j_username;
                  this.saveConnectedUser(this.connectedUser);
                  this.updateSessionTimeOut();
                  if (this.role === 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
                    this._router.navigate(['home']);
                  }
                } else {
                  this.showErrorMsgDetail = true;
                  this.error = true;
                }
              },
              error => {
                this.error = true;
              }
            );
          } else {
          }
        },
        err => {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            this.showErrorMsgDetail = true;
            this.errorMsgDetail = 'Bad credentials, try again';
          }
        }
      );
    }
```

The problem is in catching the response code from the service to the component, at component level **err.status** is undefined.

Hope you guys can figure this out.

Comment: Can you show a little more of the component code?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to communicate without any Event Emitter or BehaviorSubject how do you want to catch the error somewhere else ?

You have to catch your error in the service, inject it in your login component in the constructor, and then you just have to call your service from your component using this.myService.getDataFromWebService(post).

```
getDataFromWebService(postData: Kpi): EventEmitter<Kpi> {
    const event: EventEmitter<Kpi> = new EventEmitter();
    this.sendPost(myService.API_PATH, postData).subscribe((data) => {
      try {
        if (this.checkError(data)) {
          const parseData: Kpi = Kpi.parse(data);
          event.emit(parseData);
        } else {
          event.emit(new Kpi());
        }
      } catch (ex) {
        this.env.error("Unknown error", "Invalid data received");
        console.log("Exception", ex);
        kpiEvent.emit(new Kpi());
      }
    });
    return event;
  }
```